# A UITextField in a UITableViewCell - UIButton

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton, uitextfield

I have successfully implemented a UITextField in a UITableViewCell. Just like this:

[image]
.

I did the above using code in: `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

Now I would like to place a UIButton underneath these 2 UITableViewCells. Can I code a UIButton in? How can I do this and where?

Thanks.

**New Button Position**

[image]

**Interface Builder**

[image]

Comment: you want button at index 2 right?

Comment: Hey Superb!.. where do you need uibutton there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the same method also,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if(indexPath.row==2)
  {
   //Create a UIButton
   //Assign target
   //Add the button as a subview to cell.contentView
  }
else
  {
   //Add the textFields
  }
}
```

To create a button code as,

```
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 44); // position in the cell and set the size of the button
    [myButton setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // add targets and actions
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // add to a view
    [cell.contentView addSubview:myButton];
```

Comment: @KingofBliss: I have done the above but how can I make the 3rd row of my UITableviewCell disappear and the button to centre itself instead of being mainly on the left side? Please see the new screenshot above. Thanks.

Comment: Change button position as 60,3,200,38

Comment: @KingofBliss: Cool! Is there a way to make the 3rd cell on the tableviewCell to disappear but for the UIButton to stay? Or do I just have to cover the 3rd cell with the UIButton? Thanks.

Comment: Its better you can add the button below the tableView

Comment: Change button position as 60,tableView.height+10,200,38

Comment: @KingofBliss: At the moment, the button is overlapping the 3rd row just like above. What's the best solution? Thanks.

Comment: @KingofBliss: The position of the button is now perfect. Please see above. I have changed `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` to return 2, and it looks ideal. I had to put the button into `indexPath==2` though. However, the button seems to be disabled and I cannot press it. Do you know why? Thanks.

Comment: @KingofBliss: Please see above for code. When I run the project, the view looks like the screenshot above. 3 cells with the button underneath. I am returning 3 in `numberOfRowsInSection`. What I what is to have 2 cells and the button underneath. Thanks. P.S. When I return 2 in `numberOfRowsInSection` and put the above button code in `if(indexPath==1)`, the button becomes disabled.

Comment: Return 2. Dont put your code in if(indexPath==1), just put it in viewDidLoad. Instead of cell.contentView use self.view

Comment: @Kingofbliss: That's beautiful. Although, this question is unrelated. Do you know how to manually insert a background image to cover the page? Thanks.

Comment: insert a image to cover page?

Comment: @KingofBliss: So I have cleared the UITable background colour by adding this line: `tblSimpleTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` in the `viewDidLoad`. It now shows a white background with the 2 tableview cells and the button. I have placed a image view in IB but the new image that I want to show isn't showing up. Do you know why?

Comment: Just make sure you have added the image to the imageView

Comment: @KingofBliss: I have but it's not working. Please see above. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to add a button to tableView's footer View

```
tableView.tableFooterView = [[[UIButton alloc] initWith:] autorelease];
```

or you can add a button to section footer view.
using the method

```
viewForFooterInSection
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to make a UIViewController the controller of the table view. That way you can add a UIButton onto the view as well as the table view.

Just make the UIViewController a UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource, create a UITableView in the UIViewController and copy the code from the UITableViewController into the UIVIewController. Then add a UIButton below it.

This is what I have done in the past. I only use UITableViewController if I want just a table view dislayed for things like lists.